# How to make a SQL query using like and multiple unordered values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have looked for answers here in the community but I could not find anything specific. I have this page where I can search the name of users previously registered in my MySQL database. I am currently using the following statements:

**PHP:** `$value = str_replace(' ', '%', $search);`

**SQL:** `"select * from user where name like '%".$value."%' order by name asc;"`

The **$search** variable comes from a search form on this same page. (The above code allows me to make queries with more than one value). For example, considering a user named *Luiz Henrique da Silva*, if I search for *Luiz*, *Luiz Henrique*, or even *Luiz Silva*, this code will work **perfectly**, listing that user.

But my problem is: if I search the name out of order, such as *Silva Henrique*, or *Silva Luiz*, the user will not be listed. How could I enable this reverse search in a simple way?

*Please note, using this code I am able to search separate values, thus my need is to make queries using disordered values!*

Comment: Can you add table structure with 2 or 3 example data. So you need to list *Luiz Henrique, Luiz Silva* when you search for *Silva Henrique or Silva Luiz*. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Sinto. This is exactly what I need. If there is a user Steve Jobs, I want to list him by searching Jobs Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$search = 'Jobs Steve';
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);
$where_condition = '';
$search_arr = explode(' ', $search);
foreach($search_arr as $key => $name) {
    if ($where_condition != '') $where_condition .= ' AND ';
  $where_condition .= " name LIKE '%$name%' ";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE $where_condition ORDER BY name ASC;";
```

`$sql` will be like a `SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%Jobs%' AND name LIKE '%Steve%' ORDER BY name ASC;`

Comment: Thought you needed 'AND'?

Comment: Yeah man! This really works perfectly. I only changed **OR** for **AND**, in order to make a more accurate search. Thanks a lot! One question: this code is SQL injection proof? I am a beginner when we talk about this kind of prevention.

Comment: Im not sure about that, because if you are concating some values to a query there is always a chance of injection.

Comment: @Sinto, another answer suggested the code like '$value = str_replace(" ", "%' and name like '%", $search)'. Is there any difference from yours?

Comment: `and name like` I think this will not be correct because if you use `AND` there must be `Jobs` & `Steve` on your search key, `Jobs xxxx` or `xxxx Steve` will not be there in your list.

Comment: @Sinto. That's exactly what I need. I want to list only the users who have both values. Alright, I will study these prevent functions. Thank you.

Comment: Is this the History channel? Why are we getting a lesson in deprecated code?

Comment: @Strawberry: I think its not..! Just added few explanation as he asked about its. I think its not a bad one. Does that caused a down vote?

Comment: Of course . Promoting archaic, insecure, and deprecated code is to be discouraged. Hence the discouragement.

Comment: Is that safe now?

Answer (score 3):

PHP:

```
$value = str_replace(" ", "%' and name like '%", $search);
```

So using each word separately. But not safe: sql injection.

Using preg_replace caters for consecutive spaces:

```
$value = preg_replace('/\s+/', "%' and name like '%", $search);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering dude. I have tried your code, but it did not work even when I search ordered values. Alright, a SQL injection-proof solution would be fine as well.

Comment: Strange, the other answer is the same as mine. I think they're right.

Comment: I just tried again placing name field before like. The code became $value = str_replace(" ", "%' and name like '%", $search). It is working perfectly, like the other correct answer.

Comment: Alright. How could I make this code SQL injection-proof?

Comment: I'd put a test before checking input contains only letters and spaces. Also replacing consecutive spaces by just one (nothing to do with injection).

Comment: I am currently using the function trim, so there isnt any consecutive space before/after the search string.

Comment: Not sufficient. Check regex replace?

Comment: I did not know regex until this very moment. The PHP manual suggests '$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str)', in order to avoid two consecutive spaces. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: I suppose it is, but putting this in comments is risky business.  I'll try to modify my answer again, now that I have a proper keyboard.

Comment: I now experienced you didn't replace single spaces.

Comment: I think your code replace every single space for "%' and name like '%". I first clean the double spaces, and then, the spaces bewteen words are replaced by the "% and...". It became like this: **str_replace(" ", "%' and name like '%", preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', trim($search));**

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to inject unsanitized user input directly into a query because someone can execute their own queries and compromise your data/security. Look into prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

As for your question, you could take the search that was provided, for example: Luiz Henrique, break it apart by whitespace so you get "Luiz" and "Henrique", then create a statement that looks something like:

`WHERE name LIKE '%Luiz%' AND name LIKE '%Henrique%'`

In this way you just keep adding `AND` `LIKE` statements for each individual component.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your code works using condition **or**, so any user containing _Henrique_ or  _Luiz_ will be listed. I need a **and** verification, in order to make a more accurate search.